# Can you open access to UDP ports on an EC2 instance with Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, iptables

I would like to allow connections to specific UDP ports on an EC2 instance from a certain IP address for a limited about of time. I can do this by adding rules to the security group from the AWS console but it's tedious Is there a way to do this programatically with something like boto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. The specific AWS EC2 API functions are [AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress.html) and [RevokeSecurityGroupIngress](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-RevokeSecurityGroupIngress.html). In boto, they map to the authorize and revoke methods of a [boto.ec2.securitygroup.SecurityGroup](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#module-boto.ec2.securitygroup) instance.

If you're in a VPC you need to add Egress methods, too.